# How is a client different from a server-peer?

Tags: gemfire

The documentation says:
GemFire clients are processes that send most or all of their data requests and updates to a GemFire server system. Clients run as standalone processes, without peers of their own.

Fundamentally, all peers communicate among themselves to manage the cache. An entry made by one peer in a region goes to all other peers. Similarly, a client's cache gets updated as soon as there is a change on the server. Also a client is allowed to make new entries into the region that will get propagated to all server peers.

What then is the real difference between a client and a server peer? Based on my understanding, both have access to all data and both can do the same operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major difference between a peer and a client is that the peer connects to all other members of the distributed system; it has at-least 2 connections open at all times to each other member in the distributed system. Clients do not need connections to all servers, a single connection to a single server is enough. Thus, you can have tens of thousands of clients, but may be only hundreds of peers. (The number of connections that the client establishes can be configured while creating a [client pool](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/gemfire_nativeclient/connection-pools/configuring-pools-attributes-example.html). You can also configure single-hop on the client, which enables it to connect directly to servers against which it wishes to operate).

The performance implication here is that peers can access any data with just one network hop, whereas clients may need at-most 2 network hops (one from client to server, one from server to the node where data lives).

The other differences are:
1. Clients can [Register interest](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/gemfire_nativeclient/client-cache/registering-interest-for-entries.html), peers cannot.
2. Clients can [register Continuous Queries](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/developing/continuous_querying/chapter_overview.html), peers cannot.